# Displaying viewmodel as dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a viewmodel that looks like this:

```
var teamViewModel = {
        teams: ko.observableArray([]),
        clearTeams: function(){
            this.teams.removeAll();
        },
        addTeam: function (id, name, isChecked) {
            t = new team(id, name, isChecked);
            this.teams.push(t);
        }
    };
```

and i am getting all teams like this:

```
function GetAvailableTeams() {

        var jqxhr =
        $.getJSON('http://localhose/Service.svc/GetTeamsAll',
          function (data) {
                teamViewModel.clearTeams();
                $.each(data.GetTeamsAllResult, 
                    function (key, val) {
                        teamViewModel.addTeam(val.TeamId, val.TeamName, true);
                    });
                ko.applyBindings(teamViewModel, document.getElementById("teamNameLabel"));
          })
    }
```

How do I data-bind a select to have the TeamName as the name and TeamId as the Value.

Here is my attempt but its saying id is not recognized:

`<select id="teamNameLabel" onclick="nextfunction()" date-theme="f" data-bind="options: teams, optionsText: 'name', value: 'id'"></select>`

I also want the id returned onchange()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `optionsValue` binding instead of `value` if you want to store just `id`:

```
<select id="teamNameLabel" data-bind="options: teams, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id'"></select>
```

When you are using `value` binding you shouldn't wrap property name with `quotes`. And in this case property will store whole `team` object.

Comment: fantastic, works great!  one other thing, when the page loads there is no optionCaption or default value, id like the optionCaption to be initialized as name[1] but change to whatever was last selected (it currently does the latter)